# ASUS X99 Deluxe Bluetooth - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, asus

I have an ASUS X99 Deluxe and I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The wireless controller works out of the box, however the bluetooth does not.

I have it activated in my BIOS settings, I tried the Ubuntu Software Center and the blue* related stuff plus the additional drivers that I could find in the system settings. I now try the bluetooth (from settings) and it seems like there's no controller visible to the OS.

Based on

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network
```

My controller is

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
```

lsusb gives

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0b05:180a ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c526 Logitech, Inc. Nano Receiver
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 2433:b200  
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 05ac:024f Apple, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 05ac:1006 Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

hciconfig --all doesn't show anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show `lsusb` and `hciconfig --all`

Comment: Thanks Jeremy I updated the post with the info you asked.

Comment: Did it work on the Live DVD/USB using Try Ubuntu?  Some changes were made in the newest Ubuntu kernel that tries to upload firmware to the device but the firmware is only available to windows

Comment: The Live DVD offers basically the same thing as the actual installation, which is what I did... So it didn't work...

Comment: Are you using the 3.13.0-46 kernel `uname -r`

Comment: No it's 3.13.0-45-generic

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git
mkdir ~/LINUX_SOURCE
cd ~/LINUX_SOURCE
sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
cd linux-3.13.0/drivers/bluetooth/
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
```

Then `gedit btusb.c` and go to line 122, it should look like

```
/*Broadcom devices with vendor specific id */
{ USB_VENDOR_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(0x0a5c, 0xff, 0x01, 0x01), .driver_info = BTUSB_BCM_PATCHRAM },
```

and add

```
/* ASUSTek Computer - Broadcom based */
{ USB_VENDOR_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(0x0b05, 0xff, 0x01, 0x01),
  .driver_info = BTUSB_BCM_PATCHRAM },
```

Make sure the spacing is correct, compare to other entries, then save and exit gedit, then you can

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb && sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko.bak
sudo cp btusb.ko  /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/

cd ~
git clone git://github.com/jessesung/hex2hcd.git
cd hex2hcd
make
```

then download this to the hex2hcd folder in home https://www.dropbox.com/s/l15adb8rx2c7kid/BCM20702A1_001.002.014.1443.1612.hex?dl=0
then `hex2hcd BCM20702A1_001.002.014.1443.1612.hex fw-0b05_180a.hcd`
and `sudo cp fw-0b05_180a.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/fw-0b05_180a.hcd`
Reboot and see if btusb is loaded `lsmod | grep btusb` if it is loaded you should see a result in terminal, if it isn't loaded `sudo modprobe btusb` and see if it is working and the hcd file might need to be copied to another location also

```
sudo cp fw-0b05_180a.hcd /lib/firmware/fw-0b05_180a.hcd
```